# If Statements on PHP with 2 Text Fields

Tags: php

I'm posting a username and password from an input form and using them to check my arrays if they are there. If both are present, i want to echo a success message and if not i want to output an error message.

My success part of the if statement is working but my error message isn't outputting when i try. Can someone please help me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Half Term Project 3 </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
    <h2> Half Term Project 3 </h2>
    <?

    $errormessage = "log in details incorrect";
    $successmessage = "You are logged in";

    $userNames[0]="Carolyne"; 
    $userNames[1]="Dave"; 
    $userNames[2]="Sharonda"; 
    $userNames[3]="Milton"; 
    $userNames[4]="Macie"; 
    $userNames[5]="Harriette";
    $userNames[6]="Gianna"; 
    $userNames[7]="Grant"; 
    $userNames[8]="Caryl"; 
    $userNames[9]="Genna"; 
    $userNames[10]="Carl";

    $passwords[0]="password"; 
    $passwords[1]="123456"; 
    $passwords[2]="master"; 
    $passwords[3]="1234"; 
    $passwords[4]="qwerty"; 
    $passwords[5]="12345"; 
    $passwords[6]="dragon"; 
    $passwords[7]="mustang"; 
    $passwords[8]="baseball"; 
    $passwords[9]="football"; 
    $passwords[10]="letmein";

    $enteredusername = $_POST["username"];
    $enteredpassword = $_POST["password"];


    for($x=0; $x<=10; $x++){
        if($enteredusername == $userNames[$x]){
            if($enteredpassword == $passwords[$x]){
            echo $successmessage;
            }
            else {
                echo $errormessage;
            }
        }
        else echo $errormessage;            
    }




    ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: How exactly is it "not working"?  If you never enter the `else` block, then clearly the `if` condition is always `true`.

Comment: `echo $errormessage;` is reached __only when__ `$enteredusername == $userNames[$x]`

Comment: I changed the code, now when i try, it echos the error message 10 times

Comment: @Dhruv: Presumably there are 10 elements in the array?  That's what loops do, they repeat an operation over an array.  You're checking against 10 elements, and it fails to match each one.

Comment: how do i change the code so that it echos the error message if its not in the array, but not 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

I avise you to rewrite your code in this way:

```
$user_found = false;
for($x=0; $x<=10; $x++){
    if($enteredusername == $userNames[$x] && $enteredpassword == $passwords[$x]) {
        $user_found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if($user_found){
    echo $successmessage;
}
else {
    echo $errormessage;
}
```

Another way to achieve the same is to use [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array) function:

```
if (in_array($enteredusername, $userNames) 
    && in_array($enteredpassword, $passwords)) {
    echo $successmessage;
} else {
    echo $errormessage;
}
```

Comment: I think in_array won't work as it expect 2nd param to be array and we are comparing strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
***
```

```html
<?php

for($x=0; $x<=10; $x++)
{
  if(($enteredusername == $userNames[$x]) && ($enteredpassword == $passwords[$x]))
{
    $message = "success";
    break;
}
else
{
$message = "failure";
}
}
echo $message;

?>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you -

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Half Term Project 3 </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
    <h2> Half Term Project 3 </h2>
    <?php

    $errormessage = "log in details incorrect";
    $successmessage = "You are logged in";

    $userNames[0]="Carolyne"; 
    $userNames[1]="Dave"; 
    $userNames[2]="Sharonda"; 
    $userNames[3]="Milton"; 
    $userNames[4]="Macie"; 
    $userNames[5]="Harriette";
    $userNames[6]="Gianna"; 
    $userNames[7]="Grant"; 
    $userNames[8]="Caryl"; 
    $userNames[9]="Genna"; 
    $userNames[10]="Carl";

    $passwords[0]="password"; 
    $passwords[1]="123456"; 
    $passwords[2]="master"; 
    $passwords[3]="1234"; 
    $passwords[4]="qwerty"; 
    $passwords[5]="12345"; 
    $passwords[6]="dragon"; 
    $passwords[7]="mustang"; 
    $passwords[8]="baseball"; 
    $passwords[9]="football"; 
    $passwords[10]="letmein";

    $enteredusername = "Carolyn";
    $enteredpassword = "password";
    $is_exist = false;

    for($x=0; $x<=10; $x++){
        if($enteredusername == $userNames[$x] && $enteredpassword == $passwords[$x]){
            $is_exist = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($is_exist) echo $successmessage;
    else echo $errormessage;

    ?>
    </div>
```

And note: `<?php ?>` tag was wrong in your code.